# preventing false positives in fortify scan

Tags: security, fortify

We consistently see a lot of false positives in our Fortify results. Is there a way I can make fortify ignore certain sections of the code? For example can I add some comment in a certain block of code which will then be overlooked by fortify.

Comment: I really don't understand the reasons for the down votes, I haven't asked for any code assistance. It was a straight forward question for anyone who has an idea about fortify. I just needed a yes or no as an answer and then I would have done the necessary research/work.

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify what language you are scanning so that can change the answer a little bit.

You can exclude files and directories either at the command line with the "-exclude" switch.  Once you figure out the syntax you can include this in your build configuration, such as pom.xml.

Look at this URL for some examples:

http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Fortify-Software-Security-Center/how-to-exclude-source-files-from-scan/td-p/6574900